# PHP cannot connect oracle in command line

Tags: php, oracle

I followed the steps to download oracle instant client and add it to PATH, add php extensions and enable it in php.ini. The basic information listed as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise x64
- PHP: 7.3.30 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2021 09:48:17) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
- Oracle instant client: instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0
- php extension for oracle database: php_oci8-2.2.0-7.3-ts-vc15-x64

After all configuration done, I test the oracle connection with following code:

```
$conn = oci_connect("testuser", "testpassword", "testtns;
if (!$conn) {
    $m = oci_error();
    echo $m['message'], "\n";
    exit;
}
else {
print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
```

The web page shows positive result: Connected to Oracle!

**Then the problem comes: When I run the same code in command line environment, it shows**:

```
<warning>PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
```

Here is some PHP configruation info:

```
$ php --ri oci8

oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.2.0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 0.0.0.0.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.events => Off => Off

Statistics =>
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
```

One obvious deviation is "Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 0.0.0.0.0"
I tried the suggestion searched from google:

- copy all contents of instantclient to Apache/bin directory and remove instantclient directory from PATH
  But, it doesnot work.

This problem costs me almost 2 days time, but still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path to [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/ru/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) libraries is specified in the `PATH` environment variable.

If you're not sure try run `where oci.dll` from a command line. If it could not find the file, then it is not in the `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, the command output two oci.dll files. After I delete one . It works now.